# what do you call a person who is good at making improvements on the way things are done?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm thinking of a skill or a characteristic trait that is descriptive of someone who is always asking him/herself: "How can this be done more effectively?"

Comment: Is it only me who can see the edit button disabled on this question?

Comment: @JonyAgarwal: It's disabled for me, too.

Comment: wow. now it's enabled again and just when I thought I would be able to gain a bit of repo by improving this post, this guy @Lamar Latrell came out of nowhere and did it himself. This guy couldn't stick with just getting upvotes on his answer :P

Comment: There are *plenty* more typos for you to hunt down @JonyAgarwal. Have fun!

Comment: "A good secretary".  Alas, they are few and far between anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Tongue in cheek a little bit, but:

An ***engineer***!

But more specifically, an ***[optimiser](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/optimize)***. In the verb form:

> "To make the best or most effective use of (a situation or resource)"

Answer (score 1):

Consider **fine-tuning** and [**fine-tuner**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fine-tune).

> fine-tune: to make small changes to (something) in order to improve the way it works or to make it exactly right ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine-tune))
>
> *One of the many reasons this perplexes me is that scientific findings, particularly in cosmology, give us strong evidence that there is a fine-tuning creator.* ([harvardichthus.org](http://www.harvardichthus.org/2015/05/this-fine-tuned-universe/))

Comment: Best answer of the bunch.